# Limb chopping device to prevent zombie infection

Tags: engineering, anatomy

zombies exist

Like bacteria their seeds are everywhere, can't be avoided.
Never being infected  is unheard off, everyone experiences it once or twice in their life.

Every person, children included are equipped with mandatory and free tools created for slicing off infected limbs and pieces of flesh with ease.

**QUESTION BELOW**

**Please design/suggest a portable device, weighing less than 10 kilograms,  which can cut human limbs and flesh with such ease that even a child could use to quickly chop off one of their limbs without adult assistance.**

**Clarifications**

The infected ones do this risky ritual because the infection equals 100% death rate while losing a limb is not 100% lethal, mathematically speaking only civilizations who sacrifice limbs and pieces of flesh will survive enough to grow and reproduce.

**Explanation on how the infection works**

the infecting agent will devour any proteic substance they might find and once the infection hits the brain, it is affected by chemicals which induce humans to devour anything they might find.

Zombies live about 9 hours before they are completely digested from within, but the same infecting agent can swap from one zombie to an healthy individual by infection, one single infecting agent can leave thousands of carcasses behind.

when the infecting agent can't find food, it will simply hybernate until one unlucky guy decides to take a walk and stomps it barefoot or touches something they weren't supposed to.

Comment: What makes you think a society in this situation could last long enough to invent, manufacture, and distribute such devices?

Comment: Surgical amputation is a difficult skill, and requires anesthesia, the aid of at least one other skilled medical expert, and precise incisions so as to leave ample skin to cover the resulting open wound. For limbs, it even requires some sort of bonesaw. This isn't plausible.

Comment: Butcher's Cleaver. If it will cut through a whole pork leg in three chops(bone included), it will do the same for your zombie wannabies. And making one is very, very cheap. Consider first aid lessons in use of tourniquet, bleeding control, infection control.

Comment: @JohnO: Anaesthesia only became routine in surgical procedures in the 19th century. Surgical amputations were performed quite successfully ever since the Antiquity.

Comment: Simply chopping off an arm or a leg will quickly result in death through blood loss. Limbs have arteries, which need to be sutured during amputation procedures. Or else something else must be done to plug the arteries. Boiling pitch comes to mind.

Comment: Chopping part is easy. Properly closing the wound is hard, a full surgery is required here. It is possible to cauterize the wound, but success rate will not be high.

Comment: @ZeissIkon what makes you think hairless monkeys with no natural weapons, deadly child bearing and weak infants and a deficit in size to strength ratio  would manage to survive the ice age in a world of giant deadly animals and diseases?

Comment: Everyone goes through this ordeal once or twice -- nearly every adult is a traumatic amputee.  Something like 10% will survive each such amputation, if I've remembered correctly.  That means 99% will die from this one cause before middle age.  Population will crash in a couple generations.

Comment: @ZeissIkon ''Overall mortality after major amputation was 44%, 66% and 85% after 1, 3 and 5 years, respectively. The 6-month and 1-year mortality in patients aged 80 years or older was, respectively, 59% or 63% after a secondary amputation <3. months versus 34% and 44% after a secondary amputation >3 months.''

Comment: @ZeissIkon Ancient humans had a mortality rate of 27% at birth and almost 47% before reaching reproduction age, they managed perfectly ... butt naked in the cold and savana while surrounded by man eating cats.

Comment: That's surgical amputations, not what amounts to a guillotine chop and cauterization (or equivalent).

Comment: Half dying before reproduction age doesn't seem like "managed perfectly" to me.  They did just about well enough not to get wiped out.

Comment: @ZeissIkon what are surgical amputations if not some dudes literally sawing off bones and hitting them with hammers? I'm looking for a more sophisticated tool than hammers and saws.

Comment: @ZeissIkon and as I mentioned, those that don't cut off their limbs manage just badly enough to get wiped out... nature is fine with well enough.

Comment: @Alexander -- Full surgery is not what the query asks for. Full surgery -- débridement & functional closure, perhaps with prosthetic fitting -- comes later. I don't read this as an "let's schedule surgery for next week" kind of scenario. As I read the question, it's unclear how a person knows they've been infected or how long it takes to notice that one is infected. I'd suspect that symptoms probably become obvious within a half our or so, so a person might have a half hour more to make the decision of how far up to lop & how much to chop! Even calling 911 / 999 is wasting precious time!

Comment: @elemtilas Well, yes, it is unclear from the question how soon (if ever) the people would get to the real surgery after the incident. If it's "never", then with current tech we won't be able to construct the device OP is asking for.

Comment: @AlexP You have a strange way to say "surgical amputations often resulted in death and even in fiction they are depicted as being gruesomely agonizing requiring many people to hold the patient-victim down while their mouths are gagged to prevent the horrific screaming". But I suppose this is why I am not a poet.

Comment: @Alexander - Heh. Well, the advertised device will ***work*** (i.e., function) whether the user ever gets to an aid station / hospital or not. That's an entirely different question!

Comment: Quick question: does this infection work like the classic walking dead one? Cause normally if such a pathogen was to enter the bloodstream, it would have been taken somewhere else in the body way before you could do anything about it. The gourmet meat cleaver would probably only be useful for superficial contamination (brushing against an infected surface) rather than an incident involving someone biting a chunk of your arm/hand/leg off. And that's assuming there are no dormant airborne bacteria falling on people's membranes/eyes/etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What a Weird World!!

Sad but true, zombie infections are on the rise, and people need to protect themselves. A fact that has not been lost by the industrious engineers at Bespore & Werlt, LLC. In fact, marketing research indicates that people are willing to pay an arm and a leg for the opportunity to live a little longer in this veil of tears!

Working with a variety of NGOs such as EAT-MI! (Easy Amputation Techniques for the Mitigation of Infection), ZaMBOnNY (Zombie Mitigation Bureau of Ontario & New York) and also federal level bureaux such as NAZI (National Anti-Zombie Institute), B&W-LLC have developped an inexpensive yet durable tool kit that will allow any citizen to lop a limb with minimal discomfort and maximal chance of survival until they can reach a local aid facility.

Research indicates that more than 75% of all zombie infections are incurred by poor self-protection practices by an individual: touching an infected object with bare hands, stepping on or brushing past an infected object with bare feet or legs.

But these things happen, and B&W-LLC are here to help! Our tool kit is lightweight and chock full of only what an individual will need to survive the *critical first five minutes after knowledge of infection*. Our lightweight BZK-I (Basic Zombie Kit) is available free through a variety of private & public grants to any citizen in need of a kit. The Kit comes in a utilitarian plastic case and includes the following:

- One standard sealed battery mini-dremel type motor housing. Anyone familiar with this time-honoured household tool can easily operate the components of the kit.
- Antiseptic wipes
- A pre-selected variety of analgesic auto-injection bands (50/50 Lidocaine-Bupivicaine mini-ampoules with 32G NoPaine! needles, the larger sized bands including 3 mini-ampoules of Minidose-EPI, premarked for IV jab infiltration)
- A pre-selected assortment of auto-zip tourniquets
- A pre-selected range of Lop-em-kwicK! gigle saw wires, carefully engineered for a rapid, clean cut of the affected part
- Three pouches of sterile starch-based hemostat (gauze format)
- One emergency clock-work motor

The components of the BZK kit weigh in at less than five kilos, case included, so nearly anyone can carry and protect themselves from Terminal Zombie Infection!

An easy to interpret, step-by-step quick-start guide is printed on the inside cover; and all components of the kit are labeled for easy identification. In addition, B&W-LLC can send a highly trained, multilingual training team to your location, be it school or workhouse or civic center to offer BAZIC -- our Basic Anti-Zombie Instructional Course at no cost to the public!

Other, more advanced or more comprehensive kits, such as our BZK-III and SHAZAM (Shoulder-pack Anti-Zombie Amputation Module) are designed for groups and for focus-trained EMT personnel. These kits are obtainable at a subsidised cost to work sites, first responder corps, paramilitary groups, militias and the like.

---

Since no such kit actually exists in the real world, some things may need additional explanation.

1. A [dremel tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YCV2kR2gWw) is a hand-held multi-function tool that can be used to saw, drill, sand or carve a variety of materials.
2. The medications listed are already in common use in surgery for pain relief and reduction of bleeding (lido-bupiv is a short-long term analgesic; epi is included in this kind of crazy emergency kit because a little bit gets your body jacked up for the survival race --- it's an adrenalin rush that will (hopefully) dull your sense of pain and allow you to fight through the procedure itself and run to the nearest aid facility; [starch hemostats](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p41qvnFn--c) are in common use in surgery and in field medicine, just pack it onto the bleeding stump and haul ass to the nearest aid facility).
3. The medication "bands" are operated by the tool's motor. The medication band is looped over the limb to be cut: the med band is placed, tightened sufficiently to break the enclosed ampoules and deliver the meds -- basically a quick and dirty nerve block -- and then automatically release after five seconds.
4. The tourniquets are basically [medical grade removable zip ties](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9q27yVxPL8). You want the tourniquet to remain on to prevent bleeding; but the aid facility staff will want to be able to remove it!
5. A [gigli saw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RucaNP8sD0s&t=31s) is a hand-operated wire saw that can cut through a leg in about 20 seconds. The kit houses an assortment of snap-on gigli components that can handle small finger amputations up to below the knee amputations. The kit is **NOT** recommended for above the knee amputation, due to higher risk of major bleeding.
6. Larger and more advanced field kits start looking more like standard military issue field surgery kits with assortments of knives (small #10 & #20 scalpel blades as well as larger skin-graft type blades). These kits aren't generally intended for solo use. The solo kits are designed to be 100% disposable. **Lop and Drop!**
7. **STANDARD CAVEATS:** This is ***nòt*** surgery, folks! This is a Lop, Drop & Run emergency self-actuated first aid procedure. You do not need 5 years of limb salvage surgery residency to accomplish this. You just need the will to forge ahead and do it. The alternative appears to be half a day of agonising auto-digestive torment until you die.

Comment: I'm DYING with the organization names, hats off

Answer (score 2):

Piano wire, electric motors, the highest density batteries that can be managed, and an emergency beacon. Wire loops are attached at strategic locations such that the closing loops will slice through the effected limb at the specified joint when pulled shut by the turning of the electric motor and held in place with surgical tape. Such a kit is for day-to-day emergency triage use only though, it exists alongside more sophisticated surgical kits that allow cleaner procedures by professionals when possible and which are used to clean up the results so the patient survives the trauma, thus the emergency beacon that is part of the kit.

As a note the most common points for infection by any agent are going to be the eyes, ears, and mouth, no amount of emergency amputation is going to help most people.